# mysql json get data where key in json is a value from another table, pure sql code

Tags: mysql, json

There is a table tbl1 with json data:

(id int autoincrement primary key unique, json_data json)

tbl1

| id | json_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"john":{"3":"56"}} |
| 2 | ...... |

There is a table tbl2 with regular data like this:

(id int autoincrement primary key, student varchar(45) unique, year int(3) unsigned)

tbl2

| id | student | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 3 |
| 2 | ...... | ... |

If I need to get data from tbl1, I can execute this query:

**select `BB`.`json_data`->>'$."john"."3"'from `tbl1` `BB`**

RESULT: **56**

But, if I need to get data from tbl1 based on data in table tbl2, ***HOW CAN WE CREATE QUERY TO GET 56 AS DATA FROM TBL1 FROM JSON_DATA COLUMN***:

**select
(select `BB`.`json_data`->>'$."`AA`.`student`"."`AA`.`year`"' from `tbl1` `BB`)
from
`tbl2` `AA` WHERE `AA`.`student` = 'john' LIMIT 1**

RESULT MUST BE: **56**

For better understanding!

As you can see, json data in tbl1 are parts of data that we can find in tbl2.

In tbl2:

**student: john, year:3**

It means in tbl1:

**json_data == {"john":{"3":"56"}}**

or in general json_data is in this format:

**{"student_name":{"study_year":"data"}}**

So, I need to get this data, if I know student_name and study_year which can be dinamicaly changed:

**select `BB`.`json_data`->>'$."john"."3"'from `tbl1` `BB`**

RESULT: **56**

Comment: Use CONCAT and build complete JSON path. Use JSON_EXTRACT() instead of ->> operator.

Comment: MySQL version??

Comment: mysql 8.0 or any with json data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data with this query too:

SELECT
json_extract(BB.json_data, concat('$."', AA.student, '"."', AA.year, '"')
FROM tab1 BB, tab2 AA

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT *, 
       JSON_EXTRACT(tbl1.json_data, 
                    CONCAT_WS('.', '$', tbl2.student, tbl2.`year`))
FROM tbl1
JOIN tbl2 USING (id)
```

If `student` may contain a char which needs in quoting while used in JSON path (space char, for example) then wrap its value with double quotes.

Comment: Thank you Akina. You answered me at the speed of light.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Akina this query is also one of many possible solutions.

select
(select

JSON_EXTRACT(`BB`.`json_data`,
CONCAT_WS('.', '$', `AA`.`student`, `AA`.`year`))

from `tab1` `BB`)
from
`tab2` `AA`

Answer (score 2):

With this similar query, you can get you data:

select (select

JSON_EXTRACT(BB.json_data, CONCAT_WS('.', '$', AA.student, AA.year))

from tab1 BB) from tab2 AA